# Need to get the MAX(the latest date from current_ts column) and integrate with my query

Tags: mysql

I have this query which is working, but now I need to get MAX(log.current_ts) from t_login table where i store all the logins and need to get the latest(current_ts) for the user and compare if that MAX(current_ts) <= gr.cert_date

```
SELECT MAX(log.current_ts) as max_ts,usr.id,tmg.group_id,mo.id as module_id,mo.url as module_url,co.pc_email,usr.last_activity,usr.userid,usr.company_id,co.cardemail,gr.cert_date as cert,gr.certified,mo.display_name,usr.fname,usr.lname,usr.email as individual_email 
 FROM t_users as usr 
 LEFT JOIN t_orders as ord ON usr.id = ord.user_id 
 LEFT JOIN t_login as log ON usr.id = log.user_id
 LEFT JOIN t_modules as mo ON ord.module_id = mo.id 
 LEFT JOIN t_module_group as tmg ON tmg.group_id = mo.module_group_id 
 LEFT JOIN t_grades as gr ON ord.id = gr.order_id 
 JOIN t_company as co ON usr.company_id = co.id 
 WHERE (tmg.group_id = 4 and tmg.group_id is not null) 
 AND max_ts(I know I'm not able to do this) <= cert_date
 AND DATE_ADD(gr.cert_date, INTERVAL 48 WEEK) 
 BETWEEN '2021-08-06 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-06 23:59:59' and gr.certified = 't'
 GROUP BY usr.id;
```

Anyone can help me or point me in a better direction.
Thank you.

Comment: Aggregated value cannot be tested in WHERE. Move problematic condition into HAVING clause. PS. Your GROUP BY expression is uncomplete/partial, so the output is not deterministic.

Comment: Tried with HAVING log.current_ts <= gr.cert_date but I get the same result.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query